# My widget doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Tags: django

I try to make a radioselect form field, but it doesn't work. I tried to do it in several ways. I can't understand the problem.

**Models.py:**

```
class Check_Result(models.Model):
    Text = models.ForeignKey(Text, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    essay = models.ForeignKey(Essay, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    checker = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    essay_rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**Forms.py:**

```
class get_check(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Check_Result
        exclude = ('Text', 'essay', 'score', 'checker')
        #widgets = {'essay_rating': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'name': 'rating'}, choices=('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'))}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(get_check, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["essay_rating"] = forms.ChoiceField(
            widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
            choices=('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
        )
```

**html:**

```
<div>
<!--{{ form.essay_rating }} -->
{% for radio in form.essay_rating %}
    {{ radio }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Also, what is the right way to write in html: with cycle or without it?
Thank you  for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the form:

```
   CHOICES=[('1','option 1'),
             ('2','option 2')]
    
    self.fields['essay_rating'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

OR

```
    self.fields['essay_rating'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this form:

```
class get_check(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Check_Result
        CHOICES = (('1', '1',), ('2', '2',), ('3', '3',), ('4', '4',), ('5', '5',))
        exclude = ('Text', 'essay', 'score', 'checker')
        widgets = {'essay_rating': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'name': 'rating'}, choices=CHOICES)}
```

It's the only way to write widget for ModelForm